# Which one must be the result of st_difference of polygons? st_touches true or st_intersects true?

Tags: postgis

I've two tables of polygons, one has 1282 polygons, other has one big polygon. I use `st_difference` to have polygons that are not part of the bigger one. After `st_difference` i tried `st_touches` on result table and one polygon table. Results were all false. On the other hand `st_intersects` gives some trues what I expected from `st_touches` function.

Why is that `st_difference` function works that way? Are there anything that fits my expectation on that function?

Comment: You should use `ST_Contains` to ensure that no part of polygons lies on the exterior of the big one.

Comment: In theory, assuming correct usage: **both**. In the reality of 15 decimal places of *IEEE Floating Point* coordinate precision, and [floating-point errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems), `ST_Touches` will likely fail on arithmetically constructed geometries (e.g. a newly created vertex would need to sit *exactly* on a vector that is represented by two (floating point) coordinates). Cannot blame PostGIS for that. `ST_SnapToGrid`, `ST_QuantizeCoordinates` and similar can help.

Comment: To get polygons that intersect, but are not contained by the big polygon, you would test st_intersects(st_exteriorring(big polygon geom column), polygons geom column) = true AND st_contains(big polygon geom, polygons geom) = false

Comment: Test the custom function ST_CarvesPolygons() and check your results, maybe this is what you expect... https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/333562/120129